# How do I change an image based on scolling?

Tags: javascript, css

Okay, so I have an image on a page that I want to change out after the page has been scrolled a given amount.

For example, lets say i have image X, and I want to change said image to image Y when the user has scrolled 100 pixels down the page.  How do I do this?

For example, lets use this:
Lets say imageX.jpg is the image loaded on the page, and lets say imageY.jpg is the image I want to transition to.

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src = "imageX.jpg" />
    <div>
        <p>
            A bunch of page text that goes on forever.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of one way to accomplish your goal. Note the timeout is used the throttle the scroll. A finer grained implementation of that can be found in underscore or lodash.

EDIT: the negative votes you are getting for your question are because you made no effort at all to accomplish this. My benefit of the doubt here is that you have no idea where to start.

```js
var img1 = 'https://svgshare.com/i/9Rx.svg';
var img2 = 'https://svgshare.com/i/9SP.svg';
var img = document.querySelector('img');

document.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(() => {
    img.src = window.scrollY > 100 ? img2 : img1;
  }, 500);
});

img.src = img1;
```

```css
img {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <img width="200" />
  <div>
    <p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p>

    <p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p>

    <p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p>

    <p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p>

    <p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p>

    <p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p>

    <p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p>

    <p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p>

    <p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p>

    <p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p>

    <p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p><p>A bunch of page text that goes on forever.</p>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```